# Django charfield blank=False, but override required=False in admin

Tags: django-forms, django-database

So I have some charfields that I want to always be required in forms, except for in the admin console. They are also 'list_editable'.

This means the easiest way to do it is to set blank=False on the model, but override required=False just for the admin form.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)

class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_editable = ('first_name', ...)
    form = MyAdminForm
```

However when a value is set, and you want to set it to null, you can't.

Django won't save it as null in the DB, it will rather try to save it as the empty string "" since it is a charfield.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It may be good to read up on django's motivation for having only one falsey value https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#null